# Scroll event not working in React using useRef/createRef

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I am trying to get a scroll to occur whenever a user clicks on the corresponding buttons. I found that you can achieve this using the `useRef` hook in React. However, it doesn't work when I press the button to scroll left and right. When I console log `ref.current`, I can see that it is grabbing the corresponding `div`. Anyone see anything going on wrong here?

```
const styles = () => ({
  paper: {
    padding: '25px',
    borderRadius: '10px'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: '16px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 3,
    letterSpacing: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  container: {
    height: '110px',
    overflowX: 'scroll'
  },
  productItemsContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    overflowX: 'scroll'

  }
});

const relatedProducts = ({
  classes, products
}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const scroll = (scrollOffset) => {
        ref.current.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
console.log(ref.current.scrollLeft);
console.log(ref.current);
  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>Discover Products</Typography>
      <button onClick={() => scroll(-80)}>LEFT</button>
      <button onClick={() => scroll(+80)}>RIGHT</button>
      <Grid className={classes.container} container direction="column" >
        <Grid item>
          <div className={classes.productItemsContainer} ref={ref}>
            {
              products
                .map((product) => {
                  return (
                    <RelatedProductItem key={product.item} product={product}  />
                  );
                })
            }
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

When I check the logs that is triggered from the event handler, I can see that the `div` is grabbed and the `scrollLeft` is still 0 and stays at 0.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to scroll manually? It seems your scrolls have no space to move left or right since child components of flex div would be fit to parent width and your child components width reduced to show all without scrolling. You need to set `width` and `min-width` in the `RelatedProductItem` component root element.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bxjtyu?file=style.css,App.tsx) that would be working fine with your main logic.

Comment: hey, thanks for your input. To answer your question about whether I am able to scroll manually, yes I can. When I manually scroll, it reveals the overflown menu items from the edges which is expected. I also set the width and min width and that didn't seem to do anything. It may just be with the react version I am using which is 16.3.2